# Back button Issue in Php page

Tags: php, mysql, browser

I have a PHP MySQL admin module where some authenticated details has been stored and displayed. When I switch from one tab to other it's okay but if ever i click the back button then it shows the following error:

```
  Document Expired: This document is no longer available.

  The requested document is not available in Firefox's cache. 
  As a security precaution, Firefox does not automatically re-request 
  sensitive documents.Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website.
```

Comment: This is normal. When you submit a form and go back, you need to resubmit it (every form on every site). Phpmyadmin has a lot of forms

Comment: To be expected. You're trying to go "back" to a page which was generated as the result of a POST operation, and that page had no-cache headers, preventing the browser from cacheing the results. Since by default POSTs will not be automatically re-performed, firefox can't display anything, so you get this message.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this if you add a `header();` at the top of your page. Documentation about header() function -> [link](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)
I hope this can help you in any form

Answer (score 0):

Besides that this is normal behaviour, you can avoid it by using ajax instead of form.